# How can I hide a control using Typescript with id of the control

Tags: angular, typescript

I am designing a page dynamically using an Angular reactive form. The control is generating from JSON file. I want to hide a control from Typescript depending upon business logic. How can I proceed? I kept the Boolean value collection in an array. array[control id] = true or false. What is the syntax to bind it in html so that control will show hide depending upon array value.

Comment: You change the value of a boolean expression in your model, and use ngIf in the template to inset or remove what you want based on this boolean expression.

Answer (score 0):

with very basic understanding you should not go and find the id for that control, rather use *ngIf with your expression and it will automatically do the job for you.

If you are having problem to club multiple lines of Html then club them with `<ng-contianer>` and use *ngIf with `<ng-container>`